# collatz-list implementation using haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement collatz-list using Haskel: 
Here's my code:

```
collatz n
     | mod n 2 == 0 = div n 2
     | otherwise =  3 * n + 1


collatzList n
        | n < 1 = error "Cannot have negative number"
collatzList
        | n == 1 = [n]
        | otherwise = n:collatzList (collatz n)
```

The error message I am getting is this: 
parse error on input `collatzList'
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( exer.hs, interpreted )
Failed, modules loaded: none.

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get different errors (using GHC 7.4.1):

```
> :load "/tmp/C.hs"
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/C.hs, interpreted )

/tmp/C.hs:9:11: Not in scope: `n'

/tmp/C.hs:9:21: Not in scope: `n'

/tmp/C.hs:10:23: Not in scope: `n'

/tmp/C.hs:10:46: Not in scope: `n'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

This is because you forgot the `n` argument in your second equation for `collatzList`. You can either add this argument

```
collatzList n
        | n < 1 = error "Cannot have negative number"
collatzList n -- the n was missing here
        | n == 1 = [n]
        | otherwise = n:collatzList (collatz n)
```

or, since the left hand sides are now the same, you can simply join it with the first one:

```
collatzList n
        | n < 1 = error "Cannot have negative number"
        | n == 1 = [n]
        | otherwise = n:collatzList (collatz n)
```

Comment: @user1462452: Yes, this compiles fine on GHC 7.4.1. Given the error message you got, I suggest double-checking your indentation. Perhaps you're mixing tabs with spaces, which has a tendency of causing "invisible" syntax errors like this.

Answer (score 2):

You are redefining `collatzList`.

```
collatzList
        | n == 1 = [n]
        | otherwise = n:collatzList (collatz n)
```

do this:

```
collatz n
     | mod n 2 == 0 = div n 2
     | otherwise =  3 * n + 1

collatzList n
        | n < 1 = error "Cannot have negative number"
        | n == 1 = [n]
        | otherwise = n:collatzList (collatz n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generating a list of values that only depend on the previous value is a typical application for the `unfoldr` function (`Data.List.unfoldr`):

```
import Data.List (unfoldr)
collatzList = unfoldr nextCollatz
      where nextCollatz n | n <= 0    = Nothing
                          | n == 1    = Just (1,0)
                          | even n    = Just (n, n `quot` 2)
                          | otherwise = Just (n, 3*n+1)
```

`unfoldr f x0` takes a starting value `x0`, and applies a function `f` to it. If `f x0` is `Nothing`, the algorithm terminates; if it is `Just (push, next)`, it adds `push` to the result list, and uses `next` as the new value for `x0`. Another example, generating squares up to 100 using unfoldr:

```
import Data.List (unfoldr)
squareList = unfoldr pow2
      where pow2 n | n > 100   = Nothing
                   | otherwise = Just (n, 2*n)
                   -- "Add n to the result list,
                   -- start next step at 2*n."
```

(And the obligatory remark about `error`: it's usually better to make the function return some dummy value. In my Collatz function above for example, the result for non-positive integers is an empty list instead of an exception.)